# Spacing of notes below a figure

Tags: floats

I've trying to adjust the spacing of the text lines of notes I have below a figure. The font size of the note is, for instance, footnotesize, but the space is the same of the regular text I have in the rest of the document, so the note looks odd and ugly with such a wasted space. I would like to have the same spacing of the footnotes.

I tried with the spacing package, but it appears that it cannot be used inside a figure float.

This is an example of what I have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{My figure}
\centering \rule{4cm}{4cm}

{\footnotesize{}Note: some explanation about the figure above. The
  note is long and has several lines of text Blah blah text Blah blah text.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `{\footnotesize Note: some explanation about the figure above. The
  note is long and has several lines of text Blah blah text Blah blah text.\par}`

Comment: Are you talking vertical spacing or the spacing between words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to end the paragraph in order to adjust the line spacing.  You can do this by adding an explicit `\par` at the end of your note, as shown below.  However, it would probably be neater to define a simple environment for your figure notes.  This is also shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{fignote}{\begin{quote}\footnotesize}{\end{quote}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{My figure}
\centering 
[Figure contents]

\bigskip
{\footnotesize\noindent Note: some explanation about the figure above. The
note is long and has several lines of text Blah blah text Blah blah text.
In theory, the interrelation of system and/or subsystem technologies must utilize
and be functionally interwoven with the preliminary qualification limit.  In
particular, any associated supporting element necessitates that urgent consideration
be applied to possible bidirectional logical relationship approaches.  Conversely,
any associated supporting element recognizes other systems' importance and the
necessity for possible bidirectional logical relationship approaches.  However, a
service-oriented paradigm is further compounded when taking into account the
evolution of specifications over a given time period.\par}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Improved figure}
\centering 
[Figure contents]

\begin{fignote} 
Note: some explanation about the figure above. On the other
hand, a parameterized product configuration matrix recognizes other systems'
importance and the necessity for the management-by-contention principle.
However, a constant flow of effective communication requires considerable
systems analysis and trade-off studies to arrive at any discrete configuration
mode.  
\end{fignote}
\end{figure}

However, a constant flow of effective communication is functionally equivalent and
parallel to the anticipated fourth-generation equipment.  Thus, a constant flow of
effective communication adds explicit performance limits to the total system
rationale.  Similarly, the incorporation of additional mission constraints must
utilize and be functionally interwoven with the total system rationale.  

\end{document}
```